# python turtle crashes with loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I have a class and functions inside the class. They all work fine but when I input the loop so that it can keep asking the user to put in another circle it crashes.  What's going on?  Everything works fine without the loop...

```
from turtle import*
snowman = 1

owl = Owlet()

s_answer = input("radius of first snowman circle?")
answer = int(s_answer)
s_xPos = input("What is your x position?")
xPos = int(s_xPos)
s_yPos = input("What is your y position?")
yPos = int(s_yPos)

#owl.__init__(xPos,yPos,answer,"black")
owl.centered_circle(xPos,yPos,answer,"black")

while snowman == True:
    answer = int(s_answer)
    s_xPos = input("What is your x position?")
    xPos = int(s_xPos)
    s_yPos = input("What is your y position?")
    yPos = int(s_yPos)

    #owl.__init__(xPos,yPos,answer,"black")
    owl.centered_circle(xPos,yPos,answer,"black")
```

Comment: What is the error message? You should use snowman either as number (=1) or as a boolean (== True).

Comment: @Jasper in python `1` is evaluated as `True` and `0` as `False` so I think this in not the problem in the example he posted.

Comment: @HerrActress I know, but it's about the style :)

Comment: there is no error, after the first circle it crashes

Comment: What is `Owlet`? It's not something imported from `turtle`, as far as I can tell. Also, you say your code crashes, which I assume means that you're getting an exception somewhere. Can you provide the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You'll never break out of that loop unless somewhere in the loop you either insert a `break` or a `snowman=False`

Comment: then how do i keep making more circles?

Comment: How about a function called make_circle(), and you could ask the user if he/she wants to make another one, in which case you'd call the function? I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is, so I don't know how to advise you.